# Почему производительность приложения падает при использовании Timer?

Tags: c#, winforms, многопоточность

Есть такой код (рисует график использования процессора, использование процессора в данное время и время работы ПК) -

```
private Thread cpuThread;
private double[] cpuArray = new double[60];

private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetCPUInfo();
    }
public void GetCPUInfo()
    {
        cpuThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.getPerformanceCounters));
        cpuThread.IsBackground = true;
        cpuThread.Start();

        CPUTitle.Text = HardwareInfo.GetCPUName();         
    }

    public TimeSpan UpTime
    {
        get
        {
            using (var uptime = new PerformanceCounter("System", "System Up Time"))
            {
                uptime.NextValue();       //Call this an extra time before reading its value
                return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(uptime.NextValue());
            }
        }
    }
    private void getPerformanceCounters()
    {
        var cpuPerfCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Processor Information", "% Processor Time", "_Total");

        while (true)
        {
            cpuArray[cpuArray.Length - 1] = Math.Round(cpuPerfCounter.NextValue(), 0);

            Array.Copy(cpuArray, 1, cpuArray, 0, cpuArray.Length - 1);

            if (CPUChart.IsHandleCreated)
            {
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { UpdateCPUChart(); });
            }
            else
            {
                //......
            }
            // will always start at 0
            dynamic firstValue = cpuPerfCounter.NextValue();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);    
            // now matches task manager reading
            dynamic secondValue = cpuPerfCounter.NextValue();
        }
    }

    private void UpdateCPUChart()
    {
        CPUChart.Series["Series1"].Points.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < cpuArray.Length - 1; ++i)
        {
            CPUChart.Series["Series1"].Points.AddY(cpuArray[i]);
        }
    }

    private void CPUTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)//интервал = 1200
    {
        string timeFormat = @"dd\:hh\:mm\:ss";

        PerformanceCounter cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
        cpuCounter.CategoryName = "Processor";
        cpuCounter.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
        cpuCounter.InstanceName = "_Total";

        dynamic firstValue = cpuCounter.NextValue();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        dynamic secondValue = cpuCounter.NextValue();
        labelUpTime.Text = UpTime.ToString(timeFormat);
        labelCPUUtil.Text = Convert.ToInt32(secondValue) + "%";
    }
```

Как только я запускаю приложение, оно начинает дико тормозить. Передвигается по экрану с большой задержкой, на действия(например переключить tabControl) так же отзывается с большой задержкой. 
Но стоит убрать эти строки -

```
dynamic firstValue = cpuCounter.NextValue();
Thread.Sleep(1000);
dynamic secondValue = cpuCounter.NextValue();
labelCPUUtil.Text = Convert.ToInt32(secondValue) + "%";
```

все сразу становится очень быстро. Самое интересное, что диспетчер задач не показывает каких-то сильных изменений в нагрузке на процессор или на оперативную память, только в первые пару секунд после запуска. А так все в приделах нормы(CPU(I56600) Utilization 6-10%, RAM 3.8/8).

Почему так?

Comment: Сразу `dynamic` в глаза бросается... UPDATE: А вообще да, ответ про Thread.Sleep.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Попробуйте не стопать GUI на секунду, а асинхронно ожидать

```
private async void CPUTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)//интервал = 1200
{
    string timeFormat = @"dd\:hh\:mm\:ss";

    PerformanceCounter cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
    cpuCounter.CategoryName = "Processor";
    cpuCounter.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
    cpuCounter.InstanceName = "_Total";

    dynamic firstValue = cpuCounter.NextValue();
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    dynamic secondValue = cpuCounter.NextValue();
    labelUpTime.Text = UpTime.ToString(timeFormat);
    labelCPUUtil.Text = Convert.ToInt32(secondValue) + "%";
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Вызов `Thread.Sleep(1000)` стопорит выполнение потока, из которого он был вызван, на одну секунду.

Зависания возникают из-за того, что метод `CPUTimer_Tick()` вызывается системным обработчиком очереди сообщений. Через эту очередь, помимо всего прочего, передаются все асинхронные запросы от операционной системы вашей программе, в том числе и вашим GUI-окнам. Получается, что при каждом срабатывании таймера вы, вместо того, чтобы быстро вернуть управление обработчику и дать ему возможность разобраться со следующими сообщениями, на одну секунду стопорите всё взаимодействие программы с внешним миром. И всё это время и операционная система, и пользователь считают вашу программу зависшей, потому что вы не даёте ей обработать системные сообщения и ответить на них.

Для избавления от проблемы вам надо завести ещё один таймер, уже одноразовый (one-shot), который вы будете запускать с односекундной задержкой из `CPUTimer_Tick()` вместо `Sleep()`.

> Самое интересное, что диспетчер задач не показывает каких-то сильных изменений в нагрузке на процессор

При засыпании потока операционная система изымает его из очереди активных и перестаёт передавать ему управление, пока не закончится действие того, что отправило поток в спячку.

> ... или на оперативную память

При чём здесь память? Она связана только с хранением данных, ход выполнения программы никак на неё не влияет.

Comment: Спасибо. Но если я заменю Thread.Sleep(1000); на           CPUSleep.Start();, то проценты нагрузки будут дергаться с 0% до 100% каждую секунду.